# An unhandled exception has occured in function 'MoveNext'

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone knows what is the cause of this error message? Here's my code that I think that triggers that error. (This is from our customization project), the error triggers when I select more than 1 item.

```
        foreach (InventoryItem line in soinvlineview.Cache.Cached)
        {
            if (line.Selected == true)
            {
                StyleColorSelected newline = PXCache<StyleColorSelected>.CreateCopy(styleselected.Insert(new StyleColorSelected()));
                newline.InventoryID = line.InventoryID;
                newline = PXCache<StyleColorSelected>.CreateCopy(styleselected.Update(newline));
                styleselected.Update(newline);
            }
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should give us some info about when this exception occurred. Obviously, this is internal exception of an enumerator, so you should give us a trace and steps to reproduce.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov hi, I updated my question, what i want to achieve is to populate the 2nd grid with the checked items after click of the "populate" button.

Comment: could you look in trace log after this error occurred and show what is written there? tracelog is under Help button.

Comment: When providing trace logs, please copy and paste entire trace log in text form instead of taking a screenshot, this helps troubleshoot the issue faster. Refer to this webpage to access trace log: http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2015/09/using-acumatica-trace.html

Comment: Thank you for the help guys, I get it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, the CreateCopy method was mandatory with ver. 4.0 and earlier. Starting ver. 4.1, you don't need to use it at all. This is how your code can be simplified:

```
foreach (InventoryItem line in soinvlineview.Cache.Cached)
{
    if (line.Selected == true)
    {
        StyleColorSelected newline = styleselected.Insert(new StyleColorSelected());
        newline.InventoryID = line.InventoryID;
        styleselected.Update(newline);
    }
}
```

I suspect, your custom StyleColorSelected DAC either has no key fields specified or attributes used on the key field(s) do not generate unique values - this results in no record inserted in PXCache (Insert method returns null instead of the inserted value) and most likely causes reported unhandled exception to occur in function 'MoveNext'. Could you please double-check implementation of the StyleColorSelected DAC and also update you code as follows to verify that key fields have unique values set and record is always inserted into PXCache.

```
foreach (InventoryItem line in soinvlineview.Cache.Cached)
{
    if (line.Selected == true)
    {
        StyleColorSelected newline = new StyleColorSelected();
        // if necessary assign unique values to key field(s) here
        newline = styleselected.Insert(newline);
        if (newline == null) throw PXException("StyleColorSelected was not inserted in the cache!");

        newline.InventoryID = line.InventoryID;
        styleselected.Update(newline);
    }
}
```

Comment: i'll try this. Thanks.